# Data Factory: Help to pass variable/parameters from master pipeline to child pipeline in nested foreach

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I want to save a file based on some rows of values I have in in my blob and an array of values from master pipeline.

For example, if my file has the row `a`, `b` and `c` and the array has the values `1` and `2`. The pipeline should generate file with filenames: `a1`, `a2`, `b1`, `b2`, `c1`, `c2`

Currently this is what I have done so far without any success:

**Master pipeline**

Defining parameter and variables for master pipeline
[image]

I have a `Set Variable` and `Execute pipeline` in my `ForEach` activity. The `Execute pipeline` is poining to my child pipeline.

[image]

**Child pipeline**

In my child pipeline, I have defined the variable. `Lookup` will look at my dataset which is pointing to my blob. `ForEach` settings has the item value `@activity('Look up IATA code').output.value`.

[image]

In `ForEach` activity, I have `Set variable` and `Copy Data`. My guess is that it is the **Set variable2** that I am doing wrong. I would like to pass the values from the array `dayArray` to my `Copy dat1`. How do I pass the correct variable?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**I tried to reproduce your scenarios in my environment. For example, if my file has the row `a`, `b` and `c` and the array has the values `1` and `2`. The pipeline should generate file with filenames: `a1`, `a2`, `b1`, `b2`, `c1`, `c2`**

> **Master pipeline and its settings**

In master pipeline first I created a parameter `dayarray` with **array datatype**
[image]
Then I took foreach activity in settings I ticked sequential and items as `@pipeline().parameters.dayarray`.
[image]
Inside ForEach activity I have set variable activity where I created variable with name `demo` and **datatype as string** and gave value as `@item()`.
[image]
Now, I Created **Child pipeline** `pipeline2` with parameter `firstvar` **with datatype string**
[image]
In master pipeline I took execute pipeline and passed invoke pipeline name as pipeline2 and value for pipeline2 parameter is `@variables('demo')`
[image]

> **Child pipeline and its settings**

I Created **Child pipeline** `pipeline2` with parameter `firstvar` **with datatype string**
[image]
In child pipeline I took a lookup activity with source dataset as blob file containing those rows.
[image]
dataset is as follows
[image]
now, I took ForEach loop in child pipeline and passed the output of lookup to it in items as `@activity('Lookup1').output.value`
[image]
Inside ForEach activity I have set variable activity where I created variable with name `demofile` and **datatype as string** and gave value as `@concat(item().Prop_0,pipeline().parameters.firstvar)` here I am concating the master pipeline variable value and child pipeline lookup output value.
[image]
now passing these values to the copy activity sink dataset to create files with those values.
**copy activity sink dataset sink dataset:**
created filename parameter for datset with string datatype.
[image]
And passed that dynamic value to filename as `@dataset().filename`
[image]
**copy activity sink settings:** here I am passing set variables value to filename dataset parmeter.
[image]

**Output**
[image]

Comment: Hi @PraktikLad, in the last step _copy activity sink settings: here I am passing set variables value to filename dataset parmeter_ I get an error when I try `@variables("demofile")`, saying **Unrecognized expression: "demofile"**

Comment: Make sure your all dynamic expression are correct as my repro

Comment: what is your settings in `copy activity source` settings in your second last picture?